# Kohana 3.2 Routes: Multiple Directories

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I have a route:

```
Route::set('foo/subdir', '<directory>/<variable>/subdir/<controller>/<action>');
```

I would like to route this url to the following controller/action:

```
/application/classes/<directory>/subdir/<controller>.php::action_<action>()
```

I already have and need this route too, which complicates things:

```
Route::set('foo', '<controller>/<variable>/<action>');
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to append the subdir to the directory

This will be possible in Kohana v3.3 using the new [Route::filter](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/develop/classes/kohana/route.php#L376) functionality. There is currently no way to do this in Kohana 3.1 or 3.2 without modifying the Route and/or Request classes.

Comment: I ultimately modified the request class to add that functionality.

Comment: Can someone please post an example of how to get this working?  Its not exactly like the Kohana docs explain a whole lot.

Answer (score 3):

Why not, as long as the default route is defined *after* the directory route.

```
Route::set('foo/subdir', '<directory>/<variable>/subdir/<controller>/<action>')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'     => 'default_directory',
        'controller'    => 'index',
        'variable'      => 'default_variable',
        'action'        => 'index',
    ));
```

Kohanas routing supports directories 'natively', there is no need to hack anything.

Please note your class names will have to include the directory name as well.

Comment: What creates the issue is the subdir. I would like to append the subdir to the directory. You code above would not go to the directory I specified in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP to catch directory and subdirectory as    /directory/subdirectory/controller/action
to match Route like // where regexp allows you to put / inside directory.  Then make little modification in your Route class to change all / to the _

It is not tested ... yet. ;) But im about to...